# Terraform - for directive in JSON

Tags: terraform

I am trying to get loop over string values in an IAM policy resources block to allow rds IAM authentication. My resource definition is:

```
  resource "aws_iam_policy" "rds_iam_authentication"{
  name    = "${title(var.environment)}RdsIamAuthentication"
  policy  = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/iam_policy.json",
    {
      aws_account_id        = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
      region         = var.region
      environment           = var.environment
      iam_rds_pg_role_name  = var.iam_rds_pg_role_name
    }
  )
}
```

The variable definition of `iam_rds_pg_role_name` in `terraform.tfvars` is as follows:

```
region                  = "eu-west-3"
environment             = "env_name"
iam_rds_pg_role_name    = ["read_only_role", "full_role"]
aws_account_id          = "1234567890"
```

And the IAM policy template file is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "rds-db:connect"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            %{ for rds_role in iam_rds_pg_role_name ~}
              "arn:aws:rds-db:${region}:${aws_account_id}:dbuser:*/${rds_role}"
            %{ endfor ~}
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I am getting an error saying

> Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character '"' after array element

Im pretty sure that issue is around json encoding however when trying to `jsonencode` the arn definition in the json like the following, the error is still present:

```
%{ for rds_role in iam_rds_pg_role_name ~}
    jsonencode("arn:aws:rds-db:${region}:${aws_account_id}:dbuser:*/${rds_role}")}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Would appreciate some explaining what I'm missing or someone pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IAM policy template file, you are missing a trailing comma for items in `Resource`:

```json
...
        "Resource": [
            %{ for rds_role in iam_rds_pg_role_name ~}
              "arn:aws:rds-db:${region}:${aws_account_id}:dbuser:*/${rds_role}",
                                                  there should be a comma here ^
            %{ endfor ~}
          ]
...
```

You can loop through both the index and item in `iam_rds_pg_role_name`, and add a comma if the index is less than `length(iam_rds_pg_role_name) - 1`:

```json
...
        "Resource": [
            %{ for index, rds_role in iam_rds_pg_role_name ~}
              "arn:aws:rds-db:${region}:${aws_account_id}:dbuser:*/${rds_role}"%{ if idx < length(iam_rds_pg_role_name) - 1 },%{ endif }
            %{ endfor ~}
          ]
...
```

Result:

```shell
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_policy.rds_iam_authentication will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "rds_iam_authentication" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "Env_nameRdsIamAuthentication"
      + name_prefix = (known after apply)
      + path        = "/"
      + policy      = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "rds-db:connect",
                        ]
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = [
                          + "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-west-3:1234567890:dbuser:*/read_only_role",
                          + "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-west-3:1234567890:dbuser:*/full_role",
                        ]
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id   = (known after apply)
      + tags_all    = (known after apply)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it resolves the problem and the IAM policy is correct with the `%{ if ... }` expression. Is there a way to avoid the extra `if idx length(iam_rds_pg_role_name) -1 ` expression and somehow make it work with some inline jsonencode() function ?

Comment: You can use [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) to avoid the ugly templating above. For your problem, it can be written like: https://gist.github.com/tk-nguyen/25d6cf87fe30e34feec33f79c13542e5